# How to create a mock object for org.asynchttpclient.AsyncHttpClient in power mock

Tags: java, unit-testing, ssl, powermock

I am new to power mock,

In my program I am using `org.asynchttpclient.AsyncHttpClient` for HTTP request.

I want to Mock that request using power mock,

But It showing Error

```
"Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: class configured 
    for SSLContext: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$TLSContext not a SSLContext"
```

I found something like :

```
@PowerMockIgnore({ "org.apache.http.conn.ssl.*", 
                   "javax.net.ssl.*",
                   "javax.crypto.*"            
                })
```

But when I am adding this it show  `NullPointerException`.

Please any one help me to create a mock object for `AsyncHttpClient` .

Comment: Please provide a **full** [mcve] --- simply show us the code you currently have. And for the record: using **PowerMock** should be the last resort; when any other mocking framework doesn't do (and you can't change your source code). You should rather start with Mockito or EasyMock instead!

Answer (score 4):

I had same issue. Adding one line worked for me:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PowerMockIgnore("javax.net.ssl.*") //Add this line.
```

Answer (score 2):

Without more information about your current test code, this is a bit of guessing; but the core point is: in most mocking frameworks, creating a **mocked** object is super-simply; like in:

```
AsyncHttpClient mockedClient = mock(AsyncHttpClient.class);
```

That's it. And now you can start specifying what should happen when code is calling method on that `mockedClient` object.

The fact that you get those exceptions probably means that you are actually not mocking anything.